# Get layer types from Predict[trainingset, Method -> {"NeuralNetwork"}]

Tags: machine-learning

I am using the Predict-Function with the NeuralNetwork-method on some training data. But I cannot figure out the characteristics of the NN that is built, especially not the layer types. How can I get more information about the NN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on 12.1.1.0 then this works by peeking into the internals of `PredictorFunction`:

```
trainingData = {0.3 -> 0, 0.4 -> 0, 0.5 -> 1, 0.6 -> 1, 0.9 -> 1};
pf = Predict[trainingData, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
First[pf]["Model"]["Network"]
```

[image: netgraph]

All sorts of other properties are visible in the rat's nest of associations in `First[pf]`.

We can go deeper and apply `Normal` to the `NetGraph` to see what specific functions are in the layers. As you can see it's all linear units and SELUs:

[image: linear units and SELUs net graph]

Comment: Thanks for that! I have a follow-up question. If I call
`Information[pf, "NetworkDepth"]` in your example I get 8. How does that fit in?

Comment: Try retraining with `pf = Predict[trainingData, Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkDepth" -> 5}]`, vary the NetworkDepth and see what the image above looks like.  I have a feeling you get 8 because there is 1 initial linear layer, then 8 pairs of SELU+Linear units, and 1 final constant layer.